# Obtain number of rows into variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

The following query gives me 2714 lines:

```
SELECT soh.No
FROM OpenSalesOrdersH soh
LEFT JOIN OpenSalesOrdersL sol ON sol.Number = soh.No
WHERE sol.Number IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY soh.No
HAVING COUNT(sol.line_no) > 0
```

What I need is a select that will put that 2714 into a variable.  Something like

```
select @numTotalOpenSalesOrders=count(soh.A_Import_Set_No)
```

But that just gives me 2714 lines of '1'.  I tried SUM to see if I can just add up all the 1s, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query actually 2714 records.

If you want to just count the number of records in the resultset, then you can simply wrap it into a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (<your query>)`:

```
SELECT @numTotalOpenSalesOrders = COUNT(*) 
FROM (
select soh.No
  from OpenSalesOrdersH soh
    left join OpenSalesOrdersL sol
      on sol.Number = soh.No
  where
    sol.Number IS NOT NULL
  group by soh.No
having count(sol.line_no) > 0
) x
```

---

Also, by looking at your query, it seems like it can be simplified in several ways :

- `left join OpenSalesOrdersL sol on sol.Number = soh.No where sol.Number IS NOT NULL` : this is functionaly equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`
- `having count(sol.line_no) > 0` : the `HAVING` clause will always be true (see the previous point)
- `group by soh.No` : not really usefull as no aggregate functions come into play

I really suspect that this whole thing can be simplified as:

```
SELECT @numTotalOpenSalesOrders = COUNT(DISTINCT soh.No)
FROM OpenSalesOrdersH soh
INNER JOIN OpenSalesOrdersL sol ON sol.Number = soh.No
```

Comment: Great explanation!  The stupid joins always screw me up.

Comment: Welcome @Dizzy49 !

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think this does what you want:

```
select count(*)
from OpenSalesOrdersH soh
where exists (select 1
              from OpenSalesOrdersL sol
              where sol.Number = soh.No and
                    sol.line_no is not null
             );
```

What is nice about this approach is you can optimize it with an index on `OpenSalesOrdersL(Number, line_no)`, so it should be quite fast as well.

Oh, and to put the value in a variable:

```
select @cnt = count(*)
. . .
```